# Primeng: Wrong height of table scrollbar in a dialog with table and other element

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Scrollbar of table is too high when the table is in a dialog with other elements embedded.

Look at the examples under the following link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-dialog?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Does anyone have any idea how this can be corrected.

**Wrong:**

[image]

**Should be like:**

[image]

Comment: Just add `scrollHeight="flex"` to prime-ng table

Answer (score 1):

To remove the outside scrollbar you can add to your `styles.css` the following:

```
.p-dialog-content {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

If you would of used `.scss` instead of `.css` you would be able to do the same in the local component (which in your case is the `app.component.scss`) rather than styling in the `styles.css` by doing it as follows:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dialog-content {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I just need a solution to set the correct height of the table. Does anyone have a solution for me?